# Webview freezing in android

Tags: android, webview, bitmap

I'm trying to capture the webview but when i'm trying to compressing the bitmap webview freezing. i tried a lot but i didn't found the solution. please help..

Here's some code :

```
        webview.getHeight();
        Picture p = webview.capturePicture();
        webview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);           
        Bitmap bitmap = pictureDrawable2Bitmap(p);
        webview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        String fname = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
        File file1 = new File(fname);
        try 
        {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file1);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 10, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


private static Bitmap pictureDrawable2Bitmap(Picture picture) 
{
    PictureDrawable pictureDrawable = new PictureDrawable(picture);
                Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try
        {
            bitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap(pictureDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),pictureDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvas.drawPicture(pictureDrawable.getPicture());
        return bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per recommendation all disk and network operation should be off the main thread
for this we have the `Thread`, `AsyncTask` and `Loader` classes available for you, I see that you are working also with a `Bitmap` on the main thread which is not recommended do to the amount of resources needed this is why we must do this process of the main thread.

On the [Android Developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html)  there is a detailed example of how to accomplish this using the mentioned classes, here is an example for you that requires a Bitmap to be load of thread (which is one of the things you are trying to do):

```
class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
    private int data = 0;

    public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
        // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    // Decode image in background.
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        data = params[0];
        return decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), data, 100, 100));
    }

    // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
            final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the method to call and load a Bitmap.

```
public void loadBitmap(int resId, ImageView imageView) {
    BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
    task.execute(resId);
}
```

As you saw above its a little tricky to work with network or disk operations but then again the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) is full of examples to tackle this problems.

Hope you can resolve your problem.